# Firebase no guarda desde dentro de una función js

Tags: javascript, firebase

Tengo el siguiente fragmento de código:

```js
firebase.initializeApp({
    apiKey: "Existe",
    authDomain: "Existe",
    projectId: "Existe"
});

var db = firebase.firestore();

function guardar(oldPassword, newPassword) {
    db.collection("users").add({
        correo: "email",
        password: "oldPassword"
    })
        .then(function (docRef) {
            console.log("Document written with ID: ", docRef.id);
        })
        .catch(function (error) {
            console.error("Error adding document: ", error);
        });

}

arrVariables = location.search.substring(1, location.search.length);
arrVariableActual = arrVariables.split("=");
var arrEmail = arrVariableActual[1].split("%40");
var email = arrEmail[0] + "@" + arrEmail[1];
document.getElementById("corr").innerHTML = email;

function leerPasswords() {

    var oldPassword = document.getElementById("contraActual").value;
    var newPassword = document.getElementById("contraNueva").value;
    //action="recoverySuccess.html"

    guardar(oldPassword, newPassword)



}
```

Con el cual quiero guardar un correo y una contraseña de un usuario, pero no me funciona. Firebase literalmente no me guarda si está dentro de la función o si tiene algo del otro código por delante de el.

Comment: Bienvenido, eso esta medio raro, pues debería de guardar sin problemas, por otro lado de esa forma que estas escribiendo la función te va a sobreescribir los datos ya que no esta registrando un documento asociado a ese usuario, tu variable db al estar fuera de la función esta como global así que no debería de tener problemas para acceder a ella, revisa la consola y ve que error muestra al momento de guardar y parte de allí.

Comment: La consola no arroja ningún error, de hecho es como si ni siquiera pudiera crear la conexión a firebase.